# eclipse java jvm terminated exit code=1

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Actually my eclipse works. I mean it give the output to any change I made in source code, there is not any problem with running. But, when I try to design mode of Frames it give me this error.

JVM terminated. Exit code=1

```
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/ali/tools/ide/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/ali/tools/ide/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140606-1215/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/ali/tools/ide/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/ali/tools/ide/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /home/ali/tools/ide/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 2050015
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/ali/tools/ide/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

I know that there are plenty of answered questions related with this error. I am searching for this error since yesterday, visited lots of forms and I made most of suggestions on answers like completely delete and reinstall Eclipse, made some changes on inst-ini file in configuraiton file, updated jdk and installed jdk-8, however, none of them solved the problem. I jammed for 2 days and I do not know what to do?

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you please help me?